# how can I construct district-level weather records from gridded level dataset?

Tags: r, shapefile, r-raster, weather, economics

I'm trying to create district-level weather records by constructing an inverse-distance weighted average of all the weather grid points within a 50 km range of the district centroid. I have daily gridded data for 50 years in NetCDF file format for my weather variable (let's say temperature) and the shapefile at district-level downloaded from GADM.

I converted my NetCDF file into a raster brick and ensure that the shapefile and raster have the same CRS. Theoretically, I know that after extracting the RasterBrick and shapefile pixels I should get the centroids for each district and calculate the distance between each grid cell and the centroid, then calculate the inverse square root matrix of these distances that should refer to my weights... However, I do not know how to code all of these steps. Does anyone have any suggestions or can help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO--help us help you.  You need to provide a reproducible example and show us what you've done.  This is a pretty complex problem--why don't you start by jumping in, and as you attempt each step come back to here if with specific problems.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.